# Vala Image Base64 in Web

Tags: linux, vala

I would like to know if in Vala (Soup.Server) I can visualize an image
that I have as a string in base64 format?

private static void default_handler (Soup.Server server,Soup.Message msg,string path,GLib.HashTable? query,Soup.ClientContext client) {

var imgStr = (string) Base64.decode ("iVBORw0....");
msg.set_response("image/jpeg",Soup.MemoryUse.COPY,"%s".printf(imgStr).data);

}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GxKR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
void handle_static_file(Soup.Server server, Soup.Message message,
            string path, HashTable? query, Soup.ClientContext context) {
        server.pause_message(message);
        handle_static_file_async.begin(server, message, path, query, context);
    }

    async void handle_static_file_async(Soup.Server server,
            Soup.Message message, string path, HashTable? query,
            Soup.ClientContext context) {
        if (path == "/" || path == "") {
            path = "index.html";
        }
        var file = File.new_for_path("static/" + path);
        try {
            var info = yield file.query_info_async("*", FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE);
            var io = yield file.read_async();
            Bytes data;
            while ((data = yield io.read_bytes_async((size_t)info.get_size())).length > 0) {
                message.response_body.append(Soup.MemoryUse.COPY,
                    data.get_data());
            }
            string content_type = info.get_content_type();
            message.set_status(Soup.Status.OK);
            message.response_headers.set_content_type(content_type, null);
        } catch (IOError.NOT_FOUND e) {
            message.set_status(404);
            message.set_response("text/plain", Soup.MemoryUse.COPY,
                ("File " + file.get_path() + " does not exist.").data);
        } catch (Error e) {
            if (debug) {
                stderr.printf("Failed to read file %s: %s\n", file.get_path(),
                    e.message);
            }
            message.set_status(500);
            message.set_response("text/plain", Soup.MemoryUse.COPY,
                e.message.data);
        } finally {
            server.unpause_message(message);
        }
    }
```